# Is there a possibility to log an event if the value changes?

Tags: angular, typescript

I had an idea to show the connection status of an usb-device via angular application.

My idea is, if the device is connected to the pc, a program sends via HTTP-Post Request the value 1 to a server (every 1s) or 0 if disconnected. Then the angular application gets the value via GET-Request.

The code below shows some part of the angular project receiving the values:

**ts**

```js
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
...
constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) {
  interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
    this.getRequest();
  });
}

status : string = '';

getRequest(){
  this.httpClient.get<Notification>('.../notification/1')
  .subscribe(notification => {
    this.status = notification.status;
  });
}
```

**html**

```html
<div *ngIf= "status === '1'">
  <img src="/assets/icons/run.png">
</div>
<div *ngIf= "status === '0'">
  <img src="/assets/icons/stop.png">
</div>
```

Currently all works fine.

For the next step I want to give out a message via console.log, if the value change from 0 to 1 or vice versa, but don't have an idea.

Comment: Is your `status` variable updating ? If yes why don't you just check if `notification.status !== this.status` and if yes then show a message ?

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it worked!